# Page number issue while creating a new page sequence in a for each

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

I have an xml which looks like this :

```
<Statement>
 <name>
 <address>
 <city>
 <Details>
  <Detail>
   <T1>
    <T2>
    <T3>
  </Detail>
 </Details>
 <Details>
  <Detail>
   <T1>
    <T2>
     <T3>
   <Detail>
   <Itemisation>
    <T1>
    <T1name>
    <time>
   </Itemisation>
  <Details>
 </Statement>
```

I am using XSL FO to create pdf and afps.
Below is how my stylesheet looks like.
I have 3 page sequences. I am facing page number issue while i added the 3rd page sequence. Until which it was ok.
A new page must be added for every Itemisation section. Thus the for each. But i see an error stating id=end-item is not unique. How do i handle the page number in this case?
Please ignore if you notice any syntax error.

```
<!-- 1st page sequence --> 
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4" id="first">
 <fo:flow>
 <fo:block  font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="justify">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="Details/Itemisations">
         <fo:inline text-align="justify" font-size="7pt" 
          font-weight="bold"><fo:leader leader-length="0.7in" leader-pattern="space" />
           page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="end-item"/> 
          </fo:inline>
          </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
             <fo:inline text-align="justify" font- 
               size="7pt" font-weight="bold"><fo:leader leader-length="0.7in" leader- 
                 pattern="space" />
                  page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="end"/> 
               </fo:inline>
            </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
              </fo:block>
         </fo:flow>
       </fo:page-sequence>

<!-- 2nd page sequence-->
<fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-first" force-page-count="no-force" >
 <fo:flow>
 <fo:block  font-size="12pt" font-weight="bold" text-align="justify">
   <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="Details/Itemisations">
         <fo:inline text-align="justify" font-size="7pt" 
          font-weight="bold"><fo:leader leader-length="0.7in" leader-pattern="space" />
           page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="end-item"/> 
          </fo:inline>
          </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
             <fo:inline text-align="justify" font- 
               size="7pt" font-weight="bold"><fo:leader leader-length="0.7in" leader- 
                 pattern="space" />
                  page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation ref-id="end"/> 
               </fo:inline>
            </xsl:otherwise>
                  </xsl:choose>
              </fo:block>
         </fo:flow>
         <fo:block id="end"/>
       </fo:page-sequence>

     <!--3rd page sequence-->
      <xsl:for-each select="Details/Itemisations">
      <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4-first-next" force-page-count="no-force" >
      <fo:flow>
      <fo:block>
        <fo:inline text-align="justify" font-size="7pt" 
         font-weight="bold"><fo:leader  leader-length="1.1in" leader-pattern="space" />
          page <fo:page-number/> of <fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="end-item"/>
         </fo:inline>
       </fo:block>
       
       </fo:flow>
      <fo:block id="end-item"/>
      </fo:page-sequence>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Perhaps `<fo:block id="end-item-{position()}"/>` and `<fo:page-number-citation-last ref-id="end-item-{position()}"/>` help.

Comment: I tried this. The result was something like " page 50 of 50 " , " page 51 of 51 ". Expecting  something like " page 50 of 85 ". 85 here would be the total page count.

Comment: I see, I thought it was just a problem of having unique ids. The wanted XSL-FO structure is not clear to me but it seems you want to move the `<fo:block id="end-item"/>` outside of the `<xsl:for-each ...>` if you want a single and unique `<fo:block id="end-item"/>`

Comment: This is giving me an error saying <fo:block> is not a valid child of <fo:root> as all my page sequences are inside my <fo:root>

Comment: Your text says: "A new page must be added for every Itemisation section". Can't you just achieve that with some `fo:block` and `page-break-after="always"`? Do you really need to map each `Itemisation` to a new `page-sequence`?